# SPARQL - Select the most relevant category of a dbpedia resource

Tags: sparql

I've a dbpedia resource and I'd like to obtain all the dbpedia categories associated. For this purpose I wrote this SPARQL query

```
SELECT ?p ?o WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rihanna> ?p ?o .
}
```

focusing only on http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject property.

The [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++SELECT+%3Fp+%3Fo+%0D%0A++++WHERE%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FRihanna%3E+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)  I've is a set of categories. Which could be a good manner to select the most relevant category which describes Rihanna singer?

Comment: How do you define "most relevant"? SPARQL is a "stupid" query language for RDF data, thus, there is no concept of relevancy in the  semantics of SPARQL

Comment: There are attempts to create summation and ranking of RDF properties with algorithms like [Page Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank). You could have a look at [LinkSUM](http://km.aifb.kit.edu/services/link/) and maybe get in touch with the authors

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz +1 for the LinkSUM reference. Its quite useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This query orders Rihanna's categories by the total number of members in each category:**

```
SELECT ?category (COUNT(?member) as ?memberCount) WHERE {
    ?member dct:subject ?category.
    { SELECT ?category WHERE { dbr:Rihanna dct:subject ?category. } }
}
ORDER BY ?memberCount
```

The assumption here is that, the fewer members a category has, the higher the relevance of that category for any particular member.

The [results for this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fcategory+%28COUNT%28%3Fmember%29+as+%3FmemberCount%29+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fmember+dct%3Asubject+%3Fcategory.%0D%0A++++%7B+SELECT+%3Fcategory+WHERE+%7B+dbr%3ARihanna+dct%3Asubject+%3Fcategory.+%7D+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3FmemberCount%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) list the following categories as most relevant to Rihanna:

- Barbadian fashion designers
- Barbadian people of Irish descent
- Barbadian Christians
- Barbadian people of Guyanese descent
- Barbadian female singers

Comment: @BaileySmith I didn't, really. The result you see is the output of Virtuoso.