# The most specific rdf type of a DBpedia resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I was wondering how DPpedia decides which rdf:type to put in the header of each resource page:
[image]

I tried computing the most "specific" category by selecting the resource category that contains the fewest members total as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040060/sparql-select-the-most-relevant-category-of-a-dbpedia-resource). But it is not a reliable heuristic, at least not for this purpose. Any suggestions how to query this entity type appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieving most specific classes of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632992/retrieving-most-specific-classes-of-instances)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this one. There are two reasons why it doesn't solve my problem: 1) due to the ontology structure, it includes some very general classes (Agent, Organization, SocialPerson) and 2) does not include any logic for qualifying the results - I'm looking for the best possible class.